# Stokes' Theorem and Surfaces

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, contour-integration, surfaces, cross-product

Stokes' Theorem states the following: \begin{equation*} \oint_c \textbf{F}\centerdot d\textbf{r}= \int\int_S (\nabla \times\textbf{F})\centerdot nd \textbf{S}\end{equation*} for a given C that is the boundary of a surface S.

Can $S$ be a closed surface, where c is the boundary, given that n= the unit normal vector correctly oriented?

Best Regards,

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $S$ can be a closed surface. In that case $$\iint\limits_S (\nabla \times {\mathbf F}) \cdot {\mathbf n} \, dS = 0$$ because we consider the boundary of $S$ to be empty.

Comment: I think what he means is $S$ being a topologically closed set of $\mathbb R^3$, but not a manifold without boundary.

Comment: @MarkFantini , can't there be an C that is the boundary of a closed S?

Comment: @DifferentialEquations: Boundries cannot be defined for a closed surface, but let's think about it and act like there is one...So we have an open surface and its boundry, let's say oriented counter clockwise. Now to close it we have to choose an arbitrary surface with the same boundry oriented clockwise, because that's the only way we can close it. Sum the boundries ccw-cw=0 of the same boundry...stokes theorem

Comment: Okay, thanks for the great explanation! @dylan7

Comment: Mark, search for duplicates of questions that were likely asked and answered previously: 
This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.

Comment: @amWhy I answered this question back in 2014. I agree that both question and answer were less than desired quality though.